# python ошибка tab/space error

Tags: python, python-3.x

я не написал полностью ошибку ведь она очень длиная вся ошибка на этом скриншоте[image: вот вся ошибка]
если что код тестировал на idle

```
print("чтобы выйти ведите exid")
while True:
    a = input("веди слово я повторю:")
    if a == "exid":
        break
    else:
    print( a )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
print("чтобы выйти ведите exid")
while True:
    a = input("веди слово я повторю:")
    if a == "exid":
        break
    else:
        print( a )
```

Последняя строка должна лежать внутри `else`, а не на одном уровне с ним

Answer (score 0):

В последней строчке Таба не хватает. Он думает, что else пустой , а программа как-то дальше идет .

Comment: «Он думает, что else пустой» - нет, `else` блок не может быть пустым (когда вы хотите, чтобы он вел себя как постой, всё же нужно дать по меньшей мере команду `pass`. Значит, он не думает, что `else` пустой, a видит синтаксическую ошибку.